# Show two sets $A\notin B$ or $B \notin A $

Tags: set-theory

See this question
[Prove that for any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A\notin B$ or $B\notin A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2811672/481640)

I am having some doubt in it

Let two sets A and B be such that

A ={ B } and B = { A } . Then both contain each other . What is wrong here ?

Principal of regularity says atleast one element is disjoint from A and A contains a set which contains A . So different objects and I guess disjoint .

Also if we keep using principal of  substituting   here then sets

A = { B }

A = { { A } }

A = { { { B } } }

.

.

I think these all sets are different because they contains different objects but then they all are equal to A .

Comment: In the linked post there is the proof of the "why".

Comment: I think I found it because$$A\displaystyle\cap B = A\displaystyle\cap \{A}\neq \phi $$

Comment: But what if B = { { A } } and A = { { B } } now we won't have the problem . I still can't get that infinite substitution sequence out of my head

Comment: Why do you think that $A \cap \{ A \} \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: Consider $A= \{ a, b , c \}$; this means that the only elements of $A$ are $a, b$ and $c$. But $\{ A \}$ has only one element: $A$, and thus there are no common elements between the two sets.

Comment: Okay so I am thinking wrong but what am I missing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131453/discussion-between-rkk-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: "I think these all sets are different because they contains different objects..." CORRECT, "... but then they all are equal to A." WRONG: they are different, and thus they are **not** all equal to A.

Comment: Then doesn't it defies law of substitution when two sets A = B then we can substitute B at place of A .

Comment: Yes we can... If $A = \{ B \}$, then we can use this "identity" in substitution; thus e.g. $\{ A \} = \{ \{ B \} \}$.

Comment: But consider again an example: $B$ is the *empty* set. Thus, $B$ has no members, while $A= \{ B \} = \{ \emptyset \}$ has one member: the *empty* set. Thus, $A \ne B$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a claim: there are real numbers $x, y$ such that $x=y+1$ and $y=x+1$.

There, I wrote it down, so there are two such real numbers! Now we can simplify and see $x=y+1=x+1$ and so $0=1$. Mathematics is inconsistent, we are all working too hard, let's go home and take a nap.

Or, more likely, writing down equations does not mean that there is a solution to these equations.

In the context of set theory $A=\{B\}$ is an equation, which we would normally posit has a solution. But this requires proof, after all, $R=\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is an equation, and Russell's paradox is exactly the statement that it has no solution.

So the short answer here is that $A=\{B\}, B=\{A\}$ simply doesn't admit a solution, assuming $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: So sir I think adding principal of regularity should get rid off all of such problem so how this defies this rule ?

Comment: Also why we can't use law of substitution here?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow these questions.